# Why doesn't Softether VPN Client's vpncmd connect to a specified server?

Tags: linux, ip, vpn

I installed Softether on Linux Mint Sonya, ran `sudo ./vpnclient start`     , then I ran `sudo ./vpncmd`   and then, followed the instructions from 
[this tutorial](http://lukeluo.blogspot.com.by/2013/11/how-to-set-up-softehter-vpn-client.html)

,pressing 2 for Management of a VPN client, then running `remoteenable` , then `niccreate`  , "se" as adapter name, `accountimport` for the file from the tutorial(with changed-updated IP address and port, and changed japan0 name for japan4):

```
# VPN Client VPN Connection Setting File
# 
# This file is exported using the VPN Client Manager.
# The contents of this file can be edited using a text editor.
# 
# When this file is imported to the Client Connection Manager
#  it can be used immediately.

declare root
{
 bool CheckServerCert false
 uint64 CreateDateTime 0
 uint64 LastConnectDateTime 0
 bool StartupAccount false
 uint64 UpdateDateTime 0

 declare ClientAuth
 {
  uint AuthType 0
  string Username vpn
 }
 declare ClientOption
 {
  string AccountName japan4
  uint AdditionalConnectionInterval 1
  uint ConnectionDisconnectSpan 0
  string DeviceName se
  bool DisableQoS false
  bool HalfConnection false
  bool HideNicInfoWindow false
  bool HideStatusWindow false
  string Hostname 125.193.56.192
  string HubName vpngate
  uint MaxConnection 1
  bool NoRoutingTracking false
  bool NoTls1 false
  bool NoUdpAcceleration false
  uint NumRetry 4294967295
  uint Port 1369
  uint PortUDP 0
  string ProxyName $
  byte ProxyPassword $
  uint ProxyPort 0
  uint ProxyType 0
  string ProxyUsername $
  bool RequireBridgeRoutingMode false
  bool RequireMonitorMode false
  uint RetryInterval 15
  bool UseCompress false
  bool UseEncrypt true
 }
}
```

till here, everything was OK, but then, when I type `accountconnect` and japan4 as the account name, and then type `accountlist`  , it seems that the status of an account is always "connectING", not "connectED", as in the example in the tutorial, and the VPN doesn't work. I wanna know why? How can I set up my own account for a given server from [this list, affiliated with official SoftEther creators](http://www.vpngate.net/en/) , not importing accounts created by others? In general , how to connect this stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately there are several flavours of VPN out there, despite attempts to standardise things such as openVPN.  The flavour used by your client seems rather odd (looking at the configuration file that is).  On the other hand you can probably clarify the question by including the exact output that you get when performing `accountconnect`.

Answer (score 0):

In the config, it appears that there is no password set. I am assuming that you have set the password in the client before connecting.

Based on the documentation, it seems that, only, Windows is supported as it requires the vpn gate plugin.

Easiest way I have found, in general, is to use SoftEther client to set up a working connection in Windows. Using the SoftEther vpn client (GUI) for windows can be helpful in exporting the config file from it. Then use the config file in Linux. That way you can exclude the config file as an issue. The SoftEther client for Windows resolves some of these things itself.

Comment: Um, SoftEther runs on Synology routers (Linux), and I've connected with a Linux client without problems. While the source certainly looks Windows-oriented, "only Windows is supported" is definitely false.

Comment: I'm aware and I've used SoftEther on Linux too. However on the VPN Gate website, it does not provide instructions to use SoftEther client on Linux. Will edit my answer to reflect that.